# rspec vote validations error: must pass hash as an argument

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to write a spec code for a vote_spec model. Not sure what exactly it is I'm doing wrong. I think it may be in the first @vote attribute in the before block.

This is how the validations should work:

```
Console
v = Vote.new(value: 1)
v.valid? #=> true

v2 = Vote.new(value: -1)
v2.valid? #=> true

v3 = Vote.new(value: 2)
v3.valid? #=> false
```

This is the error:

```
Failure/Error: @vote = Vote.create(:post_id)
 ArgumentError:
   When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

This is my vote_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Vote do

describe "validations" do

    before do
        @vote = Vote.create(:post_id)
        @vote.create(value: 1)
        @vote.create(value: -1)
    end 

    describe "first_validation" do
        it "only allows -1 as a value" do
            expect(@vote.first_validation).to eq(-1)
        end
    end

    describe "second_validation" do
        it "only allows 1 as a value" do
            expect(@vote.second_validation).to eq(1)
        end
    end             
end
```

end

Comment: What are you trying to do here? ``@vote = Vote.create(:post_id)``

Comment: Overall, I'm trying to validate voting for posts, limited to only 1 or -1

Comment: What do you expect to happen when a value that is not 1 and -1 is passed?

Comment: Should return 'false'

Comment: The immediate issue here is the way you're creating a vote. The `new` and `create` methods expect hashes, not just symbols. You need `{post_id: something}`. If you just give it `post_id`, what's Rails going to infer from that?

Comment: Moreover, you shouldn't NEED to give your vote a post_id, as others have noted, just to test its `value` validations. I'd just do `Vote.new(value: whatever)`, as you basically do in the console snippet.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test validation, maybe you could do something like this:

```
describe "validations" do
  it 'is valid if the value is 1' do
    expect(Vote.new(value: 1)).to be_valid
  end    

  it 'is valid if the value is -1' do
    expect(Vote.new(value: -1)).to be_valid
  end  

  [-3, 0, 4].each do |invalid_value|
    it "is not valid if the value is #{invalid_value}" do
      expect(Vote.new(value: invalid_value)).not_to be_valid
    end
  end       
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Amanjot,

Also as Sasha mentioned in the comments. You can just continue with this below code I think

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Vote do

describe "validations" do

    before do
        @first_vote = Vote.create(value: -1) #  Vote.new(value: -1) - should try this too
        @second_vote= Vote.create(value: 1) # Vote.new(value: 1) -  should try this too
    end 

    describe "first_validation" do
        it "only allows -1 as a value" do
            expect(@first_vote.value).to eq(-1)
        end
    end

    describe "second_validation" do
        it "only allows 1 as a value" do
            expect(@second_vote.value).to eq(1)
        end
    end             
end
```

Try out something like this. You would need to use the `create` action on the Vote model.